# Como validar um provedor específico de e-mail com javascript

Tags: javascript, email, validação

A situação é a seguinte:
A empresa "batatinha" fornece o e-mail para os administradores. Então o e-mail deles é: fulano@batatinha.com.br
Porém, outros usuários podem entrar nesse sistema também com e-mails diversos.

Eu preciso que a função identifique que tipo de usuário ele é (pra poder direcionar pra página de admin ou de usuário comum no momento em que ele realiza o login) através do e-mail que consta o @batatinha.com.br.

Se for @batatinha = direciona pra tela de admin

Se não for = tela geral.

Já procurei em tudo que vocês podem imaginar, mas só acho validação de e-mail comum, nada pra verificar o que vem depois do @.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o [SPLIT](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para fazer essa validação.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim `conteudo.split("@")[1]`

Comment: Importante em próximas perguntas explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada junto de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a [função split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Essa função divide uma string em um array contendo várias a partir de um separador. Por exemplo:

```
'usuario@provedor.com'.split("@")
// ['usuario', 'provedor.com']

'email-sem-arroba'.split("@")
// ['email-sem-arroba']
```

Dessa forma, você consegue comparar o segundo item do array, ou seja, o que estiver após o arroba, com o que você precisa. Veja:

```
const checkEmailDomain = (emailAddress, domain) => {
  return emailAddress.split("@")[1] === domain
}

checkEmailDomain("vini@gmail.com", "gmail.com")
// true

checkEmailDomain("vini@gmail.com", "yahoo.com")
// false
```

Lembrando que um endereço de email pode ter mais de um caractere arroba, por mais que a maioria esmagadora dos provedores não aceite (por exemplo `"usuario@qualquercoisa"@provedor.com`). Nesse caso, o algoritmo acima não funcionaria, por estar comparando sempre com o segundo item da lista.

Comment: MUITÍSSIMO obrigada! Fiz isso e resolveu. Muito obrigada mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo as normas [RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322) e [RFC 6854](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6854), um endereço de e-mail deve se ater ao seguinte formato:

> **parte_local** **@** **domínio**

Onde o domínio pode ser um um nome de domínio([RFC 882](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc882) and [RFC 883](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc883)) ou um endereço IP entre colchetes.

A parte local do endereço de e-mail pode estar sem aspas ou entre aspas e pode ter até 64 octetos de comprimento.

Se não estiver entre aspas, parte local pode usar qualquer um destes caracteres ASCII :

- letras latinas maiúsculas e minúsculas de `A a Z`.
- dígitos de `0 a 9`.
- caracteres imprimíveis ``` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_``{|}~ ```.
- ponto `.` desde que não seja o primeiro ou último caractere e desde que também não apareça consecutivamente.

Se a parte local for uma string entre aspas:

- espaço e caracteres especiais `"(),:;<>@[\]` são permitidos tanto a barra invertida e as aspas duplas devem ser precedidas uma vez por uma barra invertida.

A parte do nome de domínio de um endereço de e-mail deve obedecer a diretrizes rígidas deve corresponder aos requisitos de um nome de host , uma lista de rótulos DNS separados por pontos , cada rótulo sendo limitado a um comprimento de 63 caracteres e consistindo em:

- letras latinas maiúsculas e minúsculas de `A a Z`.
- dígitos de `0 a 9`, desde que os nomes de domínio de nível superior não sejam todos numéricos.
- hífen `-`  desde que não seja o primeiro nem o último caractere.

Além disso, o domínio pode ser um literal de endereço IP , entre colchetes [].

Segundo esse padrão são sintaticamente validos os endereços de email:

- `fulano@batatinha.com.br`
- `"fulano@@@@@ciclano"@batatinha.com.br`

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/538431/137387) cobre casos como `fulano@batatinha.com.br` porem como informado falha ao analisar casos como `"fulano@@@@@ciclano"@batatinha.com.br` pois em síntese a função de análise de endereços de email divide o endereço na primeira ocorrência do caractere `@` assumindo que do array retornado o elemento de índice 0 é parte local e o elemento de índice 1 é o domínio. Veja o exemplo:

```js
console.log('fulano@batatinha.com.br'.split("@"));
// OK ["fulano", "batatinha.com.br"] 
// parte local: "fulano"
// domínio: "batatinha.com.br"

console.log('"fulano@@@@@ciclano"@batatinha.com.br'.split("@"));
// FALHA ["\"fulano", "", "", "", "", "ciclano\"", "batatinha.com.br"]
// parte local: "fulano"
// domínio: ""
```

Então uma abordagem em conformidade as normas RFC5322 e RFC6854 seria obter o índice da última ocorrência do caractere `@` dentro do endereço de email e a partir dessa última ocorrência colher a substring restante.

O índice da última ocorrência duma string dentro doutra string pode ser obtido com o método [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf). A partir desse índice é possível obter a substring contendo o domínio com método [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

```js
const checkEmailDomain = (address, domain) => {
  const sep = address.lastIndexOf("@");         // Obtem o indice do separador(ultimo caractere @).
  if (sep == -1) return false;                  // Se não houver um separador termina retornando falso.
  return address.substring(sep + 1) === domain; // Compara o domínio do endereço com o dominio exigido e retorna o resultado da comparacão. 
}

console.log(checkEmailDomain('batatinha.com.br', 'batatinha.com.br'));
// false

console.log(checkEmailDomain('fulano@batatinha.com.br', 'batatinha.com.br'));
// true

console.log(checkEmailDomain('fulano@gmail.com', 'batatinha.com.br'));
// false

console.log(checkEmailDomain('"fulano@@@@ciclano"@batatinha.com.br', 'batatinha.com.br'));
// true
```